# How can I insert Armenian string to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2005, unicode, internationalization

How can I insert Armenian string to SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no language expert but I think Armenian character set falls into the unicode under: U+0530–U+058F (From this url: http://unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch07.pdf)

If it's unicode, the table columns' data type need to support unicode double-byte e.g. nvarchar.

Though Armenian is not explicitly supported, see:
[International Features in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

You might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I have set Charset as `utf8` and Collation as `utf8_bin`  in database, works fine for me.
Also it is necessary to define web page's encoding as utf8, for that just write this code in your head section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and you should also define charset before making a query, something like

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password');
mysql_select_db("database_name");
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');
```

Answer (score 1):

if we assume `[myColumn] NVARCHAR(255)` in table `[myTable]`

```
INSERT INTO [myTable] (
    [myColumn]
)
VALUES (
    N'հայերեն նախադասություն'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table with Nvarchar Datatype
insert into Table(NvarcharColumn) VALUES(N'Հայերեն');